# How to iterate through widgets with different Views

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-sliver

Am beginner in flutter. I have four widgets with different view i.e. `BarChart, LineChart, StackedBarChart and CircularChart`. Then i created a List

```
 final List<Widget> widgetList = <Widget>[
    BarChartWidget(), LineChartWidget(), StackedBarChartWidget(), CircularChartWidget(),];
```

How can i iterate through List of this widgets in ListView

```
 body: new ListView.separated(
                itemCount: entries.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 150,
                    color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
                    child: new widgetList[index],
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
                )
                );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The issue is:

```dart
child: new widgetList[index],
```

That's not a valid syntax. You cannot "new" `widgetList`, as it is a variable.

Just do:

```dart
child: widgetList[index],
```

Here's the final syntax:

```dart
  new ListView.separated(
    itemCount: entries.length,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        height: 150,
        color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
        child: widgetList[index],
      );
    },
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
  );
```